# Work verification and alternative solution: sufficient condition for a Banach algebra to be commutative

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I have to prove the following:

> Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with unit $e.$ If there exists $M>0$ such that $\Vert xy \Vert \leq M \Vert yx \Vert$ for all $x, y \in A,$ then the function $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \mapsto \exp(-\lambda x)y  \exp(\lambda x) \in A$ is constant in $\mathbb{C}$ and, as a consequence, $A$ is commutative.

This is what I've done:

> **Preliminary work**
>
> Recall that, for each $x \in A,$ we define $$ \exp(x) := \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma
> e^z (ze-x)^{-1} \, dz := \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_a^b e^{\Gamma(t)} \Gamma'(t) (\Gamma(t)e-x)^{-1} \, dt,$$ where $\Gamma \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is any path that goes around $\sigma(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and the second integral is a Bochner integral.
>
> Notice that
>   $$(ze-x)^{-1} = \frac{1}{z} \left( e-\frac{x}{z}\right)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{z^{n+1}}$$
>   provided that $\Vert x/z \Vert < 1$ or, equivalently, $|z|>\Vert x \Vert.$ And since this series converges uniformly on $\text{supp } \Gamma$ (seeing $z$ as the variable), we have
>   $$ \exp(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma e^z \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{z^{n+1}}  \, dz = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \left( \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{e^z}{z^{n+1}} \, dz \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!};$$
>   in the last equal sign we have used Cauchy's formula for derivatives and the fact that all the derivatives of the complex exponential at 0 equal 1.
>
> This implies that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ for any $x, y \in A$ with $xy=yx.$ Indeed, in that case, we can use Newton's binomial theorem to obtain that
>   $$\exp(x+y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+y)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k y^{n-k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} \frac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!},$$ and because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$ and $\sum_{m=0}^\infty y^m/m!$ converge absolutely, this equals
>   $$\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \right) \left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{y^m}{m!} \right) = \exp(x)\exp(y).$$
>
> **Proof**
>
> Fix $x,y \in A$ and call $F \colon \mathbb{C} \to A$ the function given by $F(\lambda) = \exp(-\lambda x) y \exp(\lambda x).$ According to our preliminary work, we have that
>   $$F(\lambda)= \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \lambda^n x^n y}{n!} \right) \left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^m x^m}{m!}\right),$$
>   and since these series converge absolutely,
>   $$F(\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k\lambda^nx^kyx^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}$$
>   for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}.$
>
> Now, if $x^* \in A^*,$ the function $x^* \circ F \colon \mathbb{C} \to\mathbb{C}$ verifies
>   $$ x^* \circ F(\lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^kx^*(x^kyx^{n-k})}{k!(n-k)!} \right] \lambda^n$$
>   for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C};$ we have proven that $x^* \circ F$ is given by a power series and hence it is an entire function.
>
> Observe that $x^* \circ F$ is bounded: for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C},$ it holds that $|x^* \circ F(\lambda)| \leq \Vert x^* \Vert \Vert \exp(-\lambda x) y \exp(\lambda x) \Vert \leq \Vert x^* \Vert M \Vert y \exp(\lambda x) \exp(-\lambda x) \Vert = \Vert x^* \Vert M$ (because $-\lambda x$ and $\lambda x$ commute). By Liouville's theorem, we conclude that $x^* \circ F(\lambda) =x^*(y)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}.$ Therefore the coefficient of $\lambda$ in the power series expansion of $x^* \circ F$ must be 0; that is, $x^*(xy) = x^*(yx).$ This is true for any $x^* \in A^*,$ and $A^*$ separates points in $A$ (as a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem), so $xy = yx.$

I'd like to know if my argument is correct and if this fact can be proven without using the power series expansion.

Comment: Your argument should go through without explicitly calculating any power series, all you need is $e^{-x} e^{x}= 1$ for all $x$, hence $\| e^{-z x} e^y e^{zx}\| ≤ C \|e^y e^{zx}e^{-zx}\| = C\|e^y\|$ and as such the function given by $z\mapsto e^{-zx}e^ye^{zx}$ is bounded (in addition to being differentiable). Your argument with functionals and Liouville can now be applied to see that the function is constant.

Comment: I would also remark that I find your preliminary work rather odd. The definition of the exponential mapping on a Banach algebra via a power series seems to me the most natural definition, but if you are working with another definition it makes sense to see that they agree. Also the conclusion where you compare the coefficients to see $xy=yx$ is completely correct, but you could motivate it more explicitly by for example taking the derivative of $e^{-z x}e^y e^{zx}$, which has to be $0$ and evaluating that at $z=0$.